# Nested conditional Gaussian random variables for Kalman Filters

Tags: dynamical-systems, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, markov-process, kalman-filter

I am trying to follow along the Kalman Filter notes from Stanford (EE 363).
https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/kf.pdf

On Slide 15, when discussing the measurement update, the notes mention that

$x_t | Y_t$ is equal to $(x_t | Y_{t-1})|(y_t|Y_{t-1}) $

I am having trouble proving this, I tried using the tower property but did not go far.

For completeness, $x_t, Y_t$ are jointly Gaussian random variables. And $x_t|Y_{t−1}$ and $y_t|Y_{t−1}$ are also jointly Gaussian. And $y_t$ is the observation of Y at time t (if I am not mistaken).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Links can break in the future, so could you add more context from the notes to your question? Also it also seems that the linked notes it doesn't explicitly define what $Y_t$. The only thing I could guess from page 9 is that it might be $Y_t=(y_0,\ldots,y_t).$

Answer (score 1):

$(x_t | Y_{t-1})|(y_t|Y_{t-1})$ is not defined. There is no definition for "double" conditioning like this.

Perhaps your instructor means

$$
p(x_t \mid Y_{t}) = \frac{p(y_t \mid x_t) p(x_t \mid Y_{t-1})}{p(y_t \mid Y_{t-1})},
$$
which is Bayes' rule.